# ConvertTo-Json truncating object

Tags: json, powershell

I have a simple object with 1 parameter being an ArrayList of objects.  I am using `ConvertTo-Json` to output this to Json.  However even if I set `-Depth 1000` I still see truncation of data.

Structure is:

```
Object
   Property
   Property - ArrayList of Object2.
```

Object 2 is a simple collection of properties.

The output I see is:

```
{
    "CheckDate":  "03 February 2016 10:12:30",
    "Versions":  [
                     {

                     },
                     {

                     }
                 ]
}
```

Calling convert on the ArrayList directly all the data is shown.  It would appear as if the `-Depth` argument is not being honored and is stuck at 2.

edit: Code to create object

```
$returnValue = New-Object System.Object
$returnValue | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CheckDate -value (Get-Date).DateTime
$versions = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# This bit is in a loop.
$app = New-Object System.Object
$app | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $name
$app | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Version -Value $version 
$versions.Add($app)

# Back out of the loop.
$returnValue | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Versions -value $versions
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the object?

Comment: @MichaelB I've amended the question with the code.

Comment: Use `PSObject` instead of `System.Object`

Comment: @RomanKuzmin If you add that as an answer I can set that as the correct response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PSObject` instead of `System.Object`. Unfortunately, I cannot provide any details, it is some internal "magic" of `ConvertTo-Json`. Interestingly, it is enough to use `PSObject` instead of the second `System.Object`.